# How can I authenticate a user?

Tags: c#, authentication

I'll keep it simple. I have a timeout which I store my database when a user uses two factor authentication. If a user is remembered, but the date has surpassed the timeout date, I would like to authenticate the user. Now I've done similar things before with send/verify code but I would like to know if there is a way to authenticate a user without having to jump through any hoops using the AuthenticationManager.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{    
    if (!ModelState.IsValid) 
    {
        return View(model);
    }    
    // This counts login failures towards account lockout
    // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, change to shouldLockout: false
    var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: true);

    switch (result) 
    {
        case SignInStatus.Success:
           return RedirectToAction("SuccessfulSignIn");
        case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
           return View("Lockout");
        case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:    
           var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Email);    
           bool Active = ActiveCheck(user);    
           bool RememberMeTimeOut = RememberMeTimeOutCheck(user);    
           if (!Active) 
           {    
               string code = await UserManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user.Id);
               ViewBag.Expired = "Password Expired";

               return RedirectToAction("ResetPassword", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code });
           }
           else if (Active && !RememberMeTimeOut) 
           {    
               return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
           }
           else 
           {
               //Quickly sign the user in
               return RedirectToAction("SuccessfulSignIn");
           }    
        case SignInStatus.Failure:
           default:
           ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt");
           return View(model);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone else is looking at this I've come to the conclusion that you cannot simply 'skip' the sign in process. To get around this I have created a code(Two factor authentication), not sent it to the user. Then verified the code. This seems to be the quickest(and in my opinion, dirty) ways of authenticating a user.

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> TwoFSignIn(string Email) {
            var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(Email);
            string code = await UserManager.GenerateTwoFactorTokenAsync(user.Id, "Email Code");
            await SignInManager.TwoFactorSignInAsync("Email Code", code, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);
            return RedirectToAction("SuccessfulSignIn");
        }
```